# Origin of probabilities in Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, probability, born-rule

The non-normalized wavefunction of a general qubit is given by:
$$|\psi\rangle=A|0\rangle+B|1\rangle.$$
The complex amplitudes $A$ and $B$ can be represented by two arrows in the complex plane:

[image]

Now the wavefunction can be multiplied by any complex number $R$ without changing the physics. This will cause the arrows $A$ and $B$ to rotate and shrink/expand together with a fixed angle between them.

Therefore two sets of points will be traced out represented by a circle with area $|A|^2$ and a circle with area $|B|^2$. These represent the sets of possible values for the amplitudes $A$ and $B$.

Thus if we become entangled with the qubit then the probabilities of finding ourselves in set $A$ (measuring $0$) or set $B$ (measuring $1$) are given by:
$$P(0)=\frac{|A|^2}{|A|^2+|B|^2}$$
$$P(1)=\frac{|B|^2}{|A|^2+|B|^2}.$$

Does this picture help to understand the origin of probabilities in quantum mechanics?

**Correction**

Let
$$A=R_Ae^{i\theta_A}$$
$$B=R_Be^{i\theta_B}$$
A general normalized wavefunction is given by:
$$|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{(R_A^2+R_B^2)^{1/2}}\large[R_Ae^{i\theta_A}+R_Be^{i\theta_B}\large]$$
Assume that I multiply the amplitudes $A$ and $B$ by
$$C=Re^{i\theta}$$
Then the normalized wavefunction becomes
$$|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{R(R_A^2+R_B^2)^{1/2}}\large[RR_Ae^{i(\theta_A+\theta)}+RR_Be^{i(\theta_B+\theta)}\large]$$
$$|\psi\rangle=\frac{e^{i\theta}}{(R_A^2+R_B^2)^{1/2}}\large[R_Ae^{i\theta_A}+R_Be^{i\theta_B}\large]$$
It seems that the only degree of freedom is a phase angle $\theta$ rather than an area as I asserted above.

Comment: Why should we associate the area of the circles you have drawn with the probabilities to measure the qubit to have value $0$ or $1$?

Comment: Each circle $A$ or $B$ represents the sets of values for the amplitudes $A$ or $B$.

Comment: Yes but why should the areas of these sets be related to the probability to measure a qubits to have value 0 or 1?

Comment: Also how would you generalize this argument to a system of 2 entangled qubits, where the states live in 4 dimensions? Your logic would lead you to consider volumes of 4 dimensional spheres, in which case the probabilities would scale with the 4-th power of the amplitude.

Comment: Well you just find yourself in one set or the other when you become entangled with either $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$. Your wavefunction has to have some overall phase. There are $|A|^2$ phases associated with $|0\rangle$ and $|B|^2$ phases associated with $|1\rangle$.

Comment: If you have an $n$-dimensional wavefunction then you have $n$ circles in the complex plane.

Comment: OK I'll accept that you can generalize this to $n$ dimensions. But I still don't really understand your argument. You can't say "the state has $|A|^2$ phases associated with $|0\rangle$ and $|B|^2$ phases associated with $|1\rangle$." There is *one* overall phase you can apply to the whole state, for example $\theta$ in the expression $|\Psi\rangle = e^{i\theta}(A|0\rangle + B|1\rangle)$. So you can't represent the state as two independent circles in the complex plane. (By the way I haven't downvoted, I think the question is ok but the answer is this proposal doesn't explain the probabilities)

Comment: As I understand it I can normalize $|\Psi\rangle$ by either first choosing an $A$ or first choosing a $B$. There are a circular area's worth of $A$s that I can pick or a circular area's worth of $B$s. These areas give the weights for obtaining eigenvalues $0$ or $1$ respectively. Maybe this argument only works with a discrete grid of amplitude values.

Comment: if you want your state to be normalized in a standard way, $\langle \psi | \psi \rangle =1$, then you have one *angle* (not an area) you can choose for $A$. Once you choose this angle, then $B$ is *completely fixed*. If you want to choose the overal normalization in a different way, then it's not so much a "circle's worth of area", you can choose the angle and the normalization arbitrarily, so it's more like an infinite amount of area, for $A$. But (in this way of doing things) once you decide what to do about $A$, you have zero freedom left for $B$. So I still don't understand the argument.

Comment: Actually you're right there's just an angle that can be chosen not an area.

Answer (score 0):

So that picture is a way to understand quantum mechanics, and in fact it's a way that Feynman used to explain it to non-technical people, which you can see in his New Zealand lectures that were videotaped, and they became the book *QED: The Strange Theory of Light and Matter*.

However it does not shed much light on the *origins of amplitudes* since that is just an axiom of how the theory works. Like you still have an abstract imaginary circle and there is no real reason to connect its area with any sort of probability, and you have not motivated how these different amplitudes can be added or multiplied in that explanation.

Just to give you what a more general argument might look like, Scott Aaronson’s paper “Is Quantum Mechanics an Island in Theory Space?” argues that there are kind of only two possibilities, two probabilistic theories, one without negative probabilities that we call classical probability, and one with destructive interference which we call quantum mechanics, so that if you take it for granted that quantum systems must have destructive interference and results of certain quantum experiments cannot be known in advance (see quantum crypto for a usage of the latter) then the only ways to describe this must use complex numbers as amplitudes.

Stuff like that. It doesn't have to be that exact argument but it does need to have that sweeping character. So for example another argument could take as its starting point the 2-spinor calculus that underlies special relativity, and maybe amplitudes are the only thing which “plays nice” with those 2-spinors, something that connects QM to other phenomena in the world maybe. But it's never going to be as simple as “just look at these circles” because you have drawn those circles in an imaginary mathematical idealization universe, and the problem for physics is how do we model things in our universe with things in such a mathematical idealization, and so there is always a translation step. So the explanation has to be starting from things in our universe, if that makes sense, and how those experiments set hard limits on what can be used to model them in the universe of ideas in your head.

Comment: Ok but I was only trying to understand the origin of probabilities rather than the origin of the complex amplitudes themselves. I'm trying to derive the Born rule.